# Group database data by a specific column

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database there I have some records. I want to show all records groupd by the ordNR how can I do it?

```
SELECT Group_concat(ordnr) ordNR, 
       koden, 
       Group_concat(wish)  wish, 
       rnamn, 
       bild, 
       pris, 
       cname, 
       onsktext, 
       restidn 
FROM   (SELECT m.ordnr    AS ordNR, 
               p.id       AS restidn, 
               t.tabnum   AS tabNum, 
               m.wishtext AS onsktext, 
               m.meaoid   AS midn, 
               m.ordcode  AS koden, 
               w.wish, 
               r.meaname  AS rnamn, 
               r.meaimg   AS bild, 
               r.meaprice AS pris, 
               k.catname  AS cname 
        FROM   cats k, 
               meals r, 
               tables t, 
               restaurant p, 
               wishes w, 
               meaorder m 
               JOIN orders c 
                 ON c.ordnr 
        WHERE  p.id = '3' 
               AND c.tabid = t.tabid 
               AND c.ordstatus = '0' 
               AND m.ordnr = c.ordnr 
               AND m.meaid = r.meaid 
               AND m.wishesid = w.id 
               AND r.catid = k.catid)T 
GROUP  BY koden, 
          rnamn, 
          bild, 
          pris, 
          cname 
ORDER  BY midn DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order first by `ordNR`, then by `midn`.